# gridview edit template validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

when i use template in edit mode with out avalidation control ,when user click edit
lins of grid turn to edit mode and page not send eny postback to server. but when i use
edit template with validation contorol ,the page sending postback to server and page is
reloads all content agaian. how can i fix so page will act like first one

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridProducts" BorderColor="Black"  DataSourceID="sourceProducts" DataKeyNames="ProductID"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" AllowSorting="true" EnablePersistedSelection="true"    runat="server">
<HeaderStyle  BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White"/>
<RowStyle BackColor="Gray" ForeColor="White" /> 
<Columns>
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="ProductID" DataField="ProductID" />
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="ProductName" DataField="ProductName" />
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ONE UNIT PRICE" DataFormatString="{0:c}" SortExpression="UnitPrice" DataField="UnitPrice" />
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS">
    <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
     <b>In Srock:</b>
      <%#Eval("UnitsInStock")%><br />
      <b>On Order:</b>
       <%#Eval("UnitsOnOrder")%><br />
       <b>Reorder</b>
        <%#Eval("ReorderLevel")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <b>In Stock:</b><%#Eval("UnitsInStock")%><br />
      <b>On Order:</b><%#Eval("UnitsOnOrder")%><br />
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtReorder" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ReorderLevel") %>' Width="30px"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RangeValidator ID="rngValidator"   MinimumValue="0"
       MaximumValue="100" ErrorMessage="Value Out Of Range" ControlToValidate="txtReorder" EnableClientScript="true" Type="Integer" runat="server">
      </asp:RangeValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:CommandField  ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceProducts" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:Northwind%>" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice,UnitsInStock,UnitsOnOrder,ReorderLevel
  FROM Products WHERE CategoryID=@CategoryID" 
   UpdateCommand="UPDATE Products SET ProductName=@ProductName,UnitPrice=@UnitPrice,
   ReorderLevel=@ReorderLevel WHERE ProductID=@ProductID">
    <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter  Name="CategoryID" ControlID="gridCategories" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Where do you get this code from? Who is teaching this way of writing code? Put your calls to a database in a separate data access class. Use stored procedures. Use code behind to separate code from the presentation code. How anyone can work this way baffles me. It must take hours just to get a simple task done. How can you see what is going on when the grid goes into edit mode?

Comment: this is  ashampel from book beginng asp.net of matthew macdonald which i learn from. you can see edit mode i template configuration. and of cours run the page and steel need the tables